# Does calculation of resistances in parallel apply to magnetic circuits too?

Tags: circuit-analysis, magnetics, electromagnetic

Like the title says.

Is 1/Rges = 1/R1 + 1/R2.... for magnetic resistances true aswell?

E.g. can we say that Rpar = R1*R2/(R1+R2) with magnetic resistances in parallel?

Comment: This is a basic theory question appropriate for [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_circuit) or any related book or resource. Not SE.

Comment: On Wikipedia it says that magnetic circuits follow the rules of electric circuits and resistances in series are calculated the same way. But nothing about resistances in parallel. I already checked wikipedia. Give me a quick reference to a source or something else and we can close this.

Comment: Lets see, if you  [google this](https://www.google.com/search?sclient=psy-ab&btnG=Search&q=magnetic+circuits+parallel) and go a few links down to [this](https://classes.soe.ucsc.edu/ee101/Winter11/Lectures/Lecture%2021.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, reluctances add the same way as resistors in parallel. That's why the centre post of an E-I transformer lamination is usually twice the area of the sides.

[image]

Comment: Question originated exactly from such a thing :)